# can not enter setup to receive code to move to ios from android

Tags: setup

iphone se was purchased from Verizon. Verizon setup the phone. i want to use Move to IOS. I have downloaded Move to IOS on my android device but  I am unable to access setup on the iphone. What is the solution?

Comment: Where did you get Move to iOS?  Is this a Verizon app?

Comment: @fbara - it's an Apple app, from Google Play - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201196 That link, btw, says reboot both phones if it doesn't work. I'd say totally wiping it wouldn't be the first step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset your phone. Go to Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.

Please note that this will remove everything on the phone.